# Vertical and Horizontal aligment with several figures and tikz figures

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

I've been having some trouble aligning multiple figures. The problem is present with png figures and tikz figures, so I guess I am missing something.

tikz figures not properly aligned:
[image]

the particular bit of code:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \input{figs/grf_left_fb.tikz}
    \input{figs/grf_fb.tikz}   
    \input{figs/phase_fb.tikz}
    \input{figs/zap_fb.tikz}
    \caption{......}
    \label{fig:feedback}
\end{figure}
```

and with png figures (both vertical and horizontal alignment needed):

[image]

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{figs/s1.eps}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{figs/s2.eps}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{figs/s3.eps}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{figs/s11.eps}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{figs/s28.eps}
    \caption{S..........}
    \label{fig:data_good_bad}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Put `\fbox{}` around each figure to see where the bounding boxes are. Probably there are different amounts of white space being included. Otherwise, provide a complete Minimum Working Example people can actually compile to reproduce the problem. You can use images from the `mwe` package for this purpose.

Comment: I think the first problem can be solved with a right aligned tabular and the second one with two more tabulars (or tabularx), the second one with top aligned columns

Answer (score 1):

Your pictures are aligned exactly as you request: in centre of text width. I suspect, that you wish, that the right borders of them also be aligned. This you can accomplish with putting each picture in `minipage` (or equivalent `parabox`) where they are aligned to right, and than all mini pages to centre.

**Edit:**
I replace my example with MWE which contain solution for first part of align problem and second part of align problem

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz,graphicx,lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[7]
    \begin{figure}[h]\centering
\begin{minipage}{77mm}\raggedleft
    \tikz\node[draw,
               minimum width=55mm, minimum height=11mm] {picture 1};
\end{minipage}\medskip

\begin{minipage}{77mm}\raggedleft
    \tikz\node[draw,label=left:label,
               minimum width=55mm, minimum height=11mm] {picture 2};
\end{minipage}
    \caption{very important figures ...}
    \label{fig:data ...}
    \end{figure}
\lipsum[7]
    \begin{figure}[h]\centering
\begin{minipage}[b][22mm][t]{55mm}
    \tikz\node[draw,
               minimum width=44mm, minimum height=11mm] {picture 3};
\end{minipage}
    \hfil
\begin{minipage}[b][22mm][t]{55mm}
    \tikz\node[draw,label=below:label,
               minimum width=44mm, minimum height=11mm] {picture 4};
\end{minipage}
    \caption{another very important figures ...}
    \label{fig:data ...}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Environment `minipage` actually has three parameters.

```
\begin{minpage}[<position>][height][inner position]{<width>} 
    text: your image 
\end{minipage}
```

equivalent result will give `\parbox` with similar syntax:

```
\parbox[<position>][height][inner position]{<width>}{ text: your image }
```

Comment: I would really appreciate if give an example.

Comment: I edit my answer and correct all errors in given examples. Thank you for your request.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution with `tabulars`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{r}
\includegraphics[height=1cm,width=5cm]{example-image-a}\\
\includegraphics[height=1cm,width=5.5cm]{example-image-a}\\
\includegraphics[height=1cm,width=4cm]{example-image-a}\\
\includegraphics[height=1cm,width=5cm]{example-image-a}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XXX}
\includegraphics[height=1cm,width=3cm]{example-image-a} & 
\includegraphics[height=1cm,width=3cm]{example-image-a} &
\includegraphics[height=1cm,width=3cm]{example-image-a}\\
\end{tabularx}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\includegraphics[height=1cm,width=3cm,valign=t]{example-image-a} & 
\includegraphics[height=2cm,width=3cm,valign=t]{example-image-a}\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]